# Qliksense: background color expression with multiple conditions

Tags: qliksense

This is the expression I've got right now, but is erroring out:

```
If([AlarmDate] = 'Yes' and [PTM/PTC] = 'enabled' and [DateDiff] <= 15, yellow())
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to have the table schema attached to the front of the column names.